# Uniquely naming png files in def loop

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, png, function

So now I can get unique files, hurrah! but it seems the second file is plotting both the first and the second plot, the third is plotting all three, fourth is plotting all four, etc. here is the new code:

```
for j in range(2):

    dhulist=pyfits.open('test.fits')
    row=5
    colum=j

    ax=[]
    val=[]
    for i in range(1600,3040):
        val.append((dhulist[0].data[i,row,colum]))
        ax.append(((((dhulist[0].header['CRPIX3'] -i)*(dhulist[0].header['CDELT3']))+5000)/1000))

    plt.plot(ax,val)
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig("5_{0}.png".format(j))
```

Comment: It seems like you've answered your own question, Why not use `"myfile{0}.png".format(song)`? Or `"myfile{0}_{1}.png".format(*songs)`

Comment: inside plt.savefig()?

Comment: The `format` method returns a string so you can use it inside the `savefig` function or assign it to a variable and pass the variable to the function. [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) can do pretty complex things, but it should be pretty easy to get going by just looking though the examples.

Comment: (Don't edit the original code of the question, because the answer will not longer make sense... Just add your edited code as a chunk below (usually marked by **EDIT**:) if problems persist...

Comment: Create a new figure with `plt.figure(0)` or `plt.figure(j)`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. But do you get my problem here? Basically I need to plot multiple files where each time something called a column is different, and I need to have each plot named uniquely. In the code above I can get multiple plots, but the second plot also has the first and so on. Otherwise my plots are correct as is the nomenclature.

Comment: It would be much easier to figure out what you wanted if you posted a small, self-contained example that shows your problem and not much else.

Comment: You should update the name of your question to reflect what you're asking (which has changed). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) is a good place to read up on what the SO community feels are and are not good questions for this forum. Take it with a grain of sand, but remember that good questions will elicit good answers.

Answer (score 0):

the `plot` function of `matplotlib` updates the current figure, or creates a new figure if there is no current figure. Here is an example that does a good job of explicitly tracking the figure object from creation to closing.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10)

for j in range(3):
    y = x ** j
    f = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, figure=f)
    f.savefig("test_{}.png".format(j))
    plt.close(f)
```

Notice that every operation that involves a figure, opening, plotting, saving, and closing explicitly references the figure object. IMHO, that's a very nice coding style and very helpful if you ever need to work with multiple figures at once. Matplotlib also lets you work with the "current figure" implicitly, which is fine if you're doing something simple. That would look more like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10)
for j in range(3):
    y = x ** j
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.savefig("test2_{}.png".format(j))
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Yes this is what I needed! Thank you all and sorry about the messy phrasing.